# Applescript and Excel find value and get column letter

Tags: excel, applescript

Is it possible to retrieve the column letter from a selected value?

Lets say that my value is on a specific cell. How can I get the column letter of that cell?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get the column letter without having to convert it from a number.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    tell window 1

        -- this will return a string like "$A$1"
        set addr to get address (cell 1 of selection)

        -- with default text delimiters, words are {"$", "A", "$", "1"}
        set col to word 2 of addr

    end tell

end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

If your cell is selected, then script bellow gives you row and column number

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    tell window 1
        set mySelection to range selection
        set myRow to first row index of mySelection
        set myCol to first column index of mySelection
        log "row=" & myRow & "   myCol=" & myCol
    end tell
end tell
```

Once you get column number, you can convert it to letter (1="A", 2="B",...) using ASCII code.

Answer (score 0):

> Lets say that my value is on a specific cell. How can I get the column
> letter of that cell?

Very easy once you know how:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  set colLetter to character 2 of (get address active cell)
end tell
-->"D"
```

Comment: What about if it's column 27 (or higher)?